# Installing Ubuntu (any distro) onto a iMac G4

Tags: 12.04, powerpc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac G4 with no OS: can Ubuntu be used?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82420/mac-g4-with-no-os-can-ubuntu-be-used)

I recently received a iMac G4 with no OS, so instead of buying OSX I though 'why not try Ubuntu'. I have it running om my laptop right now so I know how to install Ubuntu in principle.

However, when I put in a **brand new hard drive** it would not load the Installation CD (it is the ppc). So I got my junk old Windows PC and installed Ubuntu 12.04 just fine until I put it back into the iMac. In there it is just showing me the Finder Icon and question mark. Even though the Ubuntu was tested and works just fine.

Comment: Did you used the PowerPC iso of Ubuntu?..

Comment: There are many questions already discussed on same topic. [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82420/mac-g4-with-no-os-can-ubuntu-be-used?rq=1) is more specific to your question. I hope this will help.

Comment: As [Amol Sale](http://askubuntu.com/users/24052/amol-sale) suggested, this might be answered by [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82420/mac-g4-with-no-os-can-ubuntu-be-used). If so, then this would be considered a duplicate of that question, and we'll probably close it as such. However, if that does not help you or you're still having trouble getting Ubuntu working on your PowerPC mac, please edit this question to provide more details (including what happened when you followed the information there). If we've already closed this in that situation, please also comment requesting reopening.

Answer (score 1):

There are sometimes community ports, but Ubuntu is not officially supported on Power PC. Please refer to the [official wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPC) for more information.

However, [this Ubuntu iso release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/) has the Power PC port that will hopefully work for you.