# How to install Ubuntu on mac powerbook g4

Tags: mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac G4 with no OS: can Ubuntu be used?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82420/mac-g4-with-no-os-can-ubuntu-be-used)

How do i install Ubuntu on a mac power book g4 running snowleapard  step by step instructions would be great.